# Parse float for Google maps using Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am getting a latitude and longitude values back from a json file that I want to pass to google maps that will be dynamic.

The values back from the json files are strings which I have converted to integers however I cannot seem to pass it to the latLng class for google to read.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

      var myLat = '-32.715883,152.165279';
      var myLong = '140.165279';
      var myStrToLat = parseFloat(myLat);
      var myStrToLong = parseFloat(myLong);
      var myCords = parseInt((myStrToLat),(myStrToLong));   
      var myObjContentString = 'blah blah' 

function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myCords);
      var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      var contentString = myObjContentString;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'blab'
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`google.maps.LatLng` actually takes two float values like

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

This means, simply pass your myStrToLat and myStrToLong to the ctro of LatLng...

```
var myCords = parseInt((myStrToLat),(myStrToLong));
```

Did you do that by mistake? The second parameter of parseInt is the radix, it can be a number between 2 and 36 and is used to calculate with different number systems.
I guess this is not what you wanted.

```
var myLat = '-32.715883,152.165279';
```

The string seems to contain both, lat and lng. Is this intended?

Comment: yes it was a mistake and now fixed. Schomax gave me the answer, thanks but your post was what I was thinking of, I guess I over complicated it, thanks

Comment: awesome, btw, please also use feature and/or accept a response so that your question can be marked as answered...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Ela `google.maps.LatLng`Class only accepts two numbers, whereas the Latitude has to be in the range of -90,+90 and Longitude in the rage of -180,+180.

Therefore, make sure your `myLat` and `myLong` variables both are one float number only. Then there is no need for any parsing. You can directly add it to the LatLng class like this

```
  var myLat = -32.715883;
  var myLong = 140.165279;

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);
```

You can find further information int the [LatLng-Description](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#LatLng)